# Monitoring and SQL Server Connection by leaving the connection open

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to monitor an SQL Server database connection and I'm either having issues or it's behaving as designed.
I would like to do this:

```
Open Connection
   Write "Open"
Leave it open for 1 minute (using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep)
   If the connection drops during this time write "Down" to the console
Close the connection
   Write "Closed" to the console
Repeat forever
```

So with my SQL Express service started I start my code I get

> Open
>   Closed
>   Open
>   Closed

(with the appropriate amount of time between)
Then right after I see "Open" again I stop my SQL Express service the next few lines I get are still

> Open
>   Closed
>   Open
>   Closed

Now if I restart my program while the SQL Express service is stopped then I get the proper exception.
Here is my code.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //
        string strConnectionString;
        string strEnabled;
        string strPath;
        strConnectionString = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\GlobalNet Direct\\DatabaseMonitor", "ConnectionString", false).ToString();
        strEnabled = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\GlobalNet Direct\\DatabaseMonitor", "Enabled", false).ToString();
        strPath = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\GlobalNet Direct\\DatabaseMonitor", "LogPath", false).ToString(); 
        do
        {
            strEnabled = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\GlobalNet Direct\\DatabaseMonitor", "Enabled", false).ToString(); 


            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);


            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();

                Console.WriteLine(myConnection.State.ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Down");

            }
            try
            {
                if (myConnection.State.ToString() == "Open")
                {
                    myConnection.Close();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine(myConnection.State.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }
        }while (strEnabled == "True");

    }
```

Comment: You do realize that's one *second*, not one *minute*...

Comment: Crap, yes I do. I'm impatient and set it to 1 second for testing then it included it in my paste.

Comment: If it takes several seconds for the SQL express service to actually close down, then you would except to see several open/closed messages  before it actually fails.

Comment: This might be something to do with connection pooling. Perhaps you app isn't actually talking to the sql server if it thinks it has an connection which it can use. If so, then if you do a select 0 after the open command it would throw an exception.